# taught more than 100 hours or taught for more than 100 hours

Tags: prepositions

When using the verb "run", I realized that we can say "I ran 2 hours last night." without including the preposition "for". I wonder if we can do the same thing to "teach"?

I have taught more than 1000 hours in total.

or do we have to use "for"?

I have taught for more than 1000 hours in total.

Comment: I'd certainly use *for* in both the cases.

Comment: I'm more likely to use "for" when it's continuous, so "I ran **for** 2 hours last night," means that you started at 7 PM and ran until 9 PM or something like that. On the other hand, "I have taught for more than 1000 hours," sounds weird because it's as if I claimed to have taught for 1000 hours *continuously*, which is quite the accomplishment!  I'd leave out the **for** in that sentence to indicate that those 1000 hours were accumulated in many sessions.

Comment: Thank you, Canadian Yankee. "Taught 1000 hrs" means cumulatively and "taught for 1000 hours" means continuously teaching for 1000 hours without break. Appreciate it.